# JavaScript help needed (YQL and JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, yql

I have this "adapted" javascript code to display funfacts about anything (in this case about movies and/or History)
However, it is built to display only one fact at a time, the user needs to press a button to display another funfact.

My question is, is there a way to display all the facts at once and not just one at a time?

```
function funfacts(o){
  var facts = document.getElementById('funfacts');
  facts.className = 'js';
  if(facts){
    var data = o.query.results.p;
    var link = facts.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    link.innerHTML = '(see all facts)';
    var out = document.createElement('p');
    out.className = 'fact';
    facts.insertBefore(out,link.parentNode);
    function seed(){
      var ran = parseInt(Math.random()*data.length);
      out.innerHTML = data[ran];
    }
    var b = document.createElement('button');
    b.innerHTML = 'get another fact';
    b.onclick = seed;
    link.parentNode.insertBefore(b,link);
    seed();
  }
}
```

```
  <script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tealdragon.net%2Fhumor%2Ffacts%2Ffacts.htm'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fli%2Fp'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=funfacts"></script>
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting so the second part shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `data` contains all of the facts in an array.  When the user clicks, the function `seed` is randomly selecting one item out of the array.

So, to display them all:

```
out.innerHTML = data.join("<br />");
```

This joins the facts into a single string, separated by newlines.

Edited to add:

Here's an example of a complete, very simple web page that displays all of the items:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="funfacts">
</div>
<script>
function funfacts(o){
  var facts = document.getElementById('funfacts');
  if(facts){
    var data = o.query.results.p;
    var out = document.createElement('p');
    out.className = 'fact';
    facts.appendChild(out);
    out.innerHTML = data.join("<br />");
  }
}
</script>
<script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tealdragon.net%2Fhumor%2Ffacts%2Ffacts.htm'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fli%2Fp'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=funfacts"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again JacobM, that did the trick, however i keep getting the button displayed, i have tried removing it but once i do it, the code stops working, if you have a little patient, would you mind to explain me how to work it out?

Comment: Edited to add an example of a complete function.

Comment: With that function, it doesnt work, it just doesnt display anything, and i dont understand why not, do you care to explain?

Comment: I finnally got it working, all i had to do was to remove the button code and leave the seed(); there to make the call/request, thanks once more JacobM!

Comment: Sorry, missed one issue: the "appending" of the element holding the facts list was dependent on the "link" element, which I had removed.  Updated my function to fix -- please try again.

Comment: Still doesnt work like that way, however, like i said in my previous comment, i got it working by leaving the seed(); thanks alot!

Comment: OK, fair enough.  It depends a lot on how your HTML is set up; I have a sample working if you want it.

Comment: If you wouldnt mind, i'd appreciate that, since i allways enjoyed tidy and clean pages, and your code is more nifty than my solution, however i dont understand how you have a working sample and, when i try to reproduce it, it does not work.

Comment: Edited to show a complete if minimal web page, rather than just the function.

Comment: Got it! You were a tremendous help, all i was missing was the respective <div> tag, thats why it was not working with me, thanks you a ton JacobM!